# javascript regex: blacklist 5 chars

Tags: javascript, regex, blacklist

I want to blacklist the following chars:

`' ( = < >`

So every char is allowed but not the 5 listed above.

How do I replace them with regex?

```
 myString.replace(regexString, '');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myString.replace(/['(=<>]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
myString.replace(/['(=<>]/g, '');
```

**Test:**

```
console.log("Hello' = (< >World!".replace(/['(=<>]/g, ''));
```

**Result:**

```
Hello World!
```

**More Info:**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html